# Should I flag all comments in a conversation that is no longer needed?

Tags: support, flags, comments, no-longer-needed

Today I flagged only one comment from a conversation which is no longer needed after edit to the post. I hoped that one flag will be enough for mod to handle the whole conversation, but only the flagged comment was deleted. Do I need to flag all comments?